# openmdao v1.7 installation and d3graph

Tags: openmdao

quick question. I just installed the new openmdao from pip and when I try to use d3graph.view_root or d3graph.view_connections I get an error saying that the template is not available. I noticed that the templates didn't get copied in the installation folder. It all works fine if I manually copy the templates to `openmdao/devtools/.`

I wonder if there is something in the setup file telling it not to copy the `'.template'` extensions or maybe I missed something in the installation. Everything else seems to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem with our seutp.py file.  I'll put a story for it in our bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

The setup.py file should be fixed now so that the missing .template and .html files are included in the distribution, so try out the new 1.7.1 release.